# React Native Navigate To Another Screen Automatically

Tags: react-native, components

I am trying to navigate back to the LogIn screen as soon as logout.js is hit.

At one point this seemed to work and then stopped and I can't work out why.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';

export default class App extends Component {
 
  componentDidMount() {
    (async () => {
       const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
       // Your fetch code
       this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
       let url = 'https://www.example.com/api/auth/logout';
       let h = new Headers();
       h.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
       h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');    
       let req = new Request(url, {
        headers: h,
        method: 'GET'
       });
       fetch(req)
       .then(response=>response.json())
       //.then(this.showData)
       .catch(this.badStuff)
    })();
    this.deleteToken()
  }

  badStuff = (err) => {
    this.setState({loaded: true, error: err.message});
  }

  deleteToken() {
    (async () => {
      const token = await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('token')
    });
    this.goToLogInScreen()
  }

  goToLogInScreen() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('LogIn')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={globalStyles.container}>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('LogIn')}
        />
      </View>
    );
} 


}
```

I need the code to:
Send the command to the API to log out
Delete the token from SecureStore
Navigate to the LogIn screen (containing the log in form).

Comment: showing any error?

Comment: no just not running - if I press the button it navigates to the correct screen but I need it done automatically

Comment: may be your code is throwing an exception.. try moving it to try catch